# I see many articles not using a/an/the when they should be, and usually it does pass my proofreader

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

It's manufactered at (a) high temperature.
Having proteins at (a)high temperature with fats is not healthy.
It makes since that we should use the article a, but somehow on doing google search, there are tons of news articles, news, and books that omits the a.

On doing a proofreading on grammarly it found no issues in not having the a.

Is their an exception rule that I don't know about?

Comment: Read sentence 1 as "manufactured at elevated heat" but not a specific heat setting of "a high temperature." Read 2 as "Having proteins at broiled settings together with fats" but not a specific heat setting of "a high temperature."

Comment: So you're saying that i can really omit the a no problem, this complicates things as i wonder how many as can i omit without encountering a grammar mistake.

Comment: This site is about English, not about commercial programs that attempt to analyse it.

Comment: Since you specifically mention news articles and book titles, this could be a simple case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese.  Titles and Headlines are allowed some unique leeway in grammar.

Comment: Don't use grammarly for proofreading. Hire a literate native speaker instead.

Answer (score 0):

It will pass grammar and proofing tests because both versions are grammatical.

Just that they parse differently and mean slightly different things.

You do not use an article when the reference is to a class, but do so when referring to an instance. Try to read up on "zero article," too.

> It's manufactured at high temperature.
>   "High temperature" is a state, a certain condition.
>
> It's manufactured at **a** high temperature.
>   "A high temperature" is temperature at a certain high level. It refers to a specific value of temperature.

Hope you get the drift.

(I note that @YosefBaskin has already stated as much in his comment at OP.)